# NullPointerException with defined array

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have a method `setColor`, returning float[]. It always returns float array with size=3.
When I use it like this:

```
 float[] color=setColor(0);
 content.setColor(Color.getHSBColor(color[0], color[1], color[2]));
```

there is a `NullPointerException`.

When I debug my program color[0], color[1], color[2] are defined, but it says that there is a NullPointerException.

How can I fix this?

Here is code of setColor

```
private float[] setColor (int colorID){
    float[]hsbValues=new float[3];
    if(colorID == 1){
        hsbValues =  Color.RGBtoHSB(0,255,255,hsbValues);
    }
    else if(colorID == 2){
        hsbValues =  Color.RGBtoHSB(255,0,255,hsbValues);
    }
    else if(colorID == 3){
        hsbValues =  Color.RGBtoHSB(0,255,0,hsbValues);
    }
    else if(colorID == 4){
        hsbValues =  Color.RGBtoHSB(255,255,0,hsbValues);
    }
    else if(colorID == 5){
        hsbValues =  Color.RGBtoHSB(255,0,0,hsbValues);
    }
    else if(colorID == 6){
        hsbValues =  Color.RGBtoHSB(255,255,255,hsbValues);
    }
    else{
        hsbValues =  Color.RGBtoHSB(0, 0, 0,hsbValues);
    }
    return hsbValues;
}
```

Here is constructor of class.

```
DrawOutput (MinDistances requiredMinDistances, MainMatrix matrix){
    super();
    getRequiredMedoidsArray(requiredMinDistances);
    paint(getGraphics(), requiredMinDistances, matrix);
}
```

getGraphics is null, Any suggestions?

Comment: The variable content may be null. Have you checked this?

Comment: Can you provide more code?

Comment: with two code lines it's pretty difficult to get a correct answer for a NullPointer.

Comment: Post your stack trace (your exception).

Comment: Yeah, sory added more code.

Comment: That code doesn't really help.

Comment: @TGMCians `color` is an array and can be null. The OP wrote it's defined though.

Comment: You say getGraphics() return null. getGraphics is a method for which class ?

Comment: @TGMCians I'm not referring to the values of the array but the array itself. But since the OP has posted the `setColor()` method we know it's not null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line can throw NPE if

1. `color` is null
2. `content` is null

If `color` is not null therefore check your `content`.

Comment: If the people who are downvoting because of `context` instead of `content` then this downvotes should be casted to upvotes.. +1 from me for correct answer with a small typo.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza, I'd like to know PID of those people. Sometimes I'd enjoy to send them `kill -9` :)

Comment: I think the downvotes are origined by the "simplicity" of what he's asking and the vague way the OP has made the question. Just saying (didn't downvote).

Answer (score 2):

The `content` variable is `null`.

Comment: The is not an answer. It's a question.

Comment: This is an answer grammatically composed as question.

Comment: You are right, it's a question... The answer is "check the variable content"

Comment: Please change the form of your question to be **an answer** (if I do it, that will be messing with your answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your NPE is in this line:

```
content.setColor(Color.getHSBColor(color[0], color[1], color[2]));
```

because `content` is `null`.

`float` array is always created here `float[] hsbValues = new float[3]` and since `color[0]`, `color[1]`, `color[2]` are `float`, they can't be `null`.

Comment: `color`is an array and can be null. In that case `color[0]` would throw a NPE.

Comment: It can't, `setColor()` always returns an array object.

Comment: That's true, I just missed that you mentioned that in your answer :)